# Can somebody help me with this?(Python 3)

Tags: python, function, variables

A variable with the name def that stores the number 7

def is a special keyword which cannot be used to store numbers, was just wandering is it possible to do so if a program syntax was used?

Comment: I don't understand the question. As you noted, `def` is one of several special keywords in Python which can't be used for variable names. So you can't use it, simple as that. Surely you can find an alternative name?

Comment: Using keywords as names of variables gives unexpected results. It may not throw an error but it will likely cause the script to execute in an unexpected manner affecting your result.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad The `SyntaxError` raised is entirely expected.

Comment: @timgeb I'm not sure about def but usually when you use keywords as name of variable it won't give you a SyntaxError

Comment: @NinadGaikwad Of course `def` does

Comment: Try it. `def = 2` --> `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @NinadGaikwad "usually when you use keywords as name of variable it won't give you a SyntaxError" <- It will give you a syntax error every single time for every keyword.

Comment: The only thing possible is to have a key `def` in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3 **def** is **used to define a function**, you could declare a function that takes a parameter and use it inside your function.

You can refer to the Documentation for more details.